# error 403 - Forbidden mutiple applications on single Codeigniter 4 installation

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I am trying to configure, multiple apps on single codeigniter 4 installation.
I followed: [manage multiple applications](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html)
and able to run my multiple apps on localhost. but on live server it gives the following error:

> ```
> Error 403 - Forbidden
> You tried to access a document for which you don't have privileges.
> ```

I have changed only the $systemDirectory in app\config\Paths.php and it worked on localhost, but on liver server no luck.
Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you need to give different permissions to folders on live server. [How to access folder on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726125/how-to-access-my-codeigniter-folder-in-ubuntu)

Comment: I have given most of the folders read, write and execute permissions.

Comment: Then check your htaccess file. May be something wrong inside htaccess.

Comment: I didn't make any changes to .htaccess file.

Comment: I tried to delete it, but no luck.